# How would you do this simple query in the most optimized way MYSQL and also MARIADB

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, query

```
pkid clientname location    
1   Jones   NY  
2   Jones   NJ  
3   Jones   TX  
4   Jones   FL  
5   Jones   IA  
6   Jones   NC  
7   Jones   SC  
8   Jones   VA  
9   Smith   FL  
10  Smith   CO  
11  Smith   NJ  
12  Smith   ME
```

---

I would like to find what client (Jones or Smith) HAS LOCATION NY, NJ AND NC and have the output as Jones.

If I  was using an in clause the query would be select clientname from table where location in ('NY','NJ','NC')  except the in clause acts as a "OR" and I need an "AND" .

Comment: Do/can Jones/Smith have different locations? And if they're the same person, why have different `PK`s?

Comment: `... HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT location) = 3`

Comment: If you can't write this query then you don't need to worry about whatever you think people mean by "optimized".

Comment: If you have only 'thousands' of rows, "most optimized" is not a big deal.  How many rows do you have?  (Meanwhile, the `HAVING` is straight-forward, and may be 'good enough'.)

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(location, clientname)  -- This is part of the optimization

SELECT clientname
    FROM tbl
    WHERE location IN ('NY', 'NJ', 'NC')
    GROUP BY clientname
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

(If there can be multiple rows, change to `COUNT(DISTINCT location)`.)

Note that the index is

- "composite"
- in the 'right' order (to handle `WHERE` first)
- "covering" (all necessary columns are in the index)

Is it optimal?  I don't know.  Its performance will depend on the version of mysql/mariadb -- there have been improvements in this area.  In one experiment with a similar query, it read only the rows (of the index) for the 3 'locations', not the entire index.  I used the technique discussed [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts) to discover the number of rows read.